# adding Array to "LET" language

Tags: scheme, racket

I have the "LET" language from the book "EOPL"
you can see also the defention of the lang in the following git:
https://github.com/svenpanne/EOPL3/blob/master/chapter3/exercise-3-10.rkt

I need to add an array to the languge and get an item in an index (the array can have any type of values include the array it self)

for example the following code should give (num-val 8) (you start from index 1 and 10-2=8)

```
let A = array {10, -(5,7) , zero?(8), array {1,2,3}, 12 }
in
 -(<A>[1] , <<A>[4]>[2])
```

I have implemnted the array using the list described in the above git by adding"

```
  (expression
   ("array" "{" expression (arbno "," expression) "}")
    array-exp)

    (array-exp (e1 exps)
      (list-exp (cons e1 exps)))
```

and  now I need to add the arr index command and got stuck with it.